# Как связать libvirt и qemu?

Tags: ubuntu, виртуализация, kvm, qemu

Имеется *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86_64 (Desktop)*, в которой установлены *libvirt-4.3.0* и *qemu-2.4.0.1*. При запуске *virt-manager*-а выдается:

> внутренняя ошибка: Не удалось найти эмулятор для x86_64

*libvirt* собран и установлен из исходников.

*qemu* также собран и установлен из исходников, ибо он патченый (нужен именно такой).

Соответственно, *qemu*, как пакет, в системе не виден, и менеджер ВМ в `qemu:///system` ничего не находит. По версиям все совместимо (согласно [табличке](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/LibvirtDistroSupportMatrix)). Демон *libvirtd* запущен.

Если поставить *qemu* через *APT*, то все работает. Но нужна именно версия `2.4.0.1`, которая доступна только в виде исходников. Собрать из них `.deb`-пакет не получилось.

[В документации](https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html) сказано:

> **QEMU emulators:** The driver will probe /usr/bin for the presence of qemu, qemu-system-x86_64, qemu-system-microblaze, qemu-system-microblazeel, qemu-system-mips,qemu-system-mipsel, qemu-system-sparc,qemu-system-ppc. The results of this can be seen from the capabilities XML output.
>   **KVM hypervisor:** The driver will probe /usr/bin for the presence of qemu-kvm and /dev/kvm device node. If both are found, then KVM fullyvirtualized, hardware accelerated guests will be available.

Создаю симлинки `qemu-kvm` и `qemu-system-x86_64`, кладу их в `/usr/bin`, перезапускаю демон - так же ошибка. Облазил все конфиги *libvirt*-a, но так и не нашел, где можно явно задать путь к *qemu* или задать кастомный *URI* вместо `qemu:///system`.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что еще можно предпринять в данной ситуации, чтобы все-таки связать *libvirt* c *qemu*?

Comment: `sudo apt install qemu-kvm`

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Так поставится _qemu-4.3.0_, а нужно перенаправить _libvirt_ на _qemu-2.4.0.1._